# Magento save(); cause app to hang

Tags: php, mysql, magento, save

I am trying to update categories to no longer be active by setting is_active to 0, but whenever the action gets to save() Magento hangs and won't save the updated database. I have to restart the server in order to use magento again. Does anyone know why it hangs on save()? We are using mysql workbench as root user so it's not a permissions issue. $todelete->delete() works without any issue

`public function onclearAction() //Clear button on sales app removes sale
    {

        echo "onclear start";
        $model = Mage::getModel('countdown/observer_category');
        foreach ($_POST['number'] as $entity_id) {
            $type = "category";
            $cat = Mage::getModel("catalog/category")->load($entity_id);
            $cat->setData('is_active', 0);
            $cat->save();
            $todelete = Mage::getModel('countdown/countdown')->getCountdown($type, $entity_id);
            $todelete->delete();
        }
        $this->_redirect('adminhtml/salesapp/index');
    }`

Comment: With the information we have, all anyone could do is guess. The only thing I see wrong with your code is you're accessing the $_POST superglobal directly. In Magento, $this->getRequest()->getPost() (or ->getParam('number')) is preferred.

Comment: It may be helpful to use try/catch to see if it's spitting out an error.   

try {
   $cat->save();
} catch(Exception $e) {
  var_dump($e);
}

Answer (score 1):

use this

```
$cat->setIsActive(1);
$cat->save();
```

I hope this would help you , don't forget to like my ans if it was help full

Comment: It still hangs at save()